# Install and use JOE Editor on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: thunderbird, text-editor, mbox

I miss Joe! I've been using Ubuntu since Ubuntu 8.04 (it was easy). 
When I learned more about computering, I got JOE and had fun.

It was always hard to change my hardware or make a complete new installation. because I run a small enterprise, being self-employed!

It was hard when I migrated my thunderbird mail.
So my project is now, restoring a 0.685GB mbox file  ;-)
Don't bash me for it.

Just give me back Joe's Own Editor for my today's Ubuntu  :-)  can you?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=joe - seems to be available for all current versions of Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

### Joe's Own Editor

I found `joe` and `joe-jupp` in the Ubuntu Universe repository.

```
sudo apt-get install joe
sudo apt-get install joe-jupp
```

[joe-editor.sourceforge.net/](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/)

I think this is what you are looking for.

### Alternatives

- I remember using `jove` long ago in UNIX and MSDOS. I think it was Jonathan's own version of emacs.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install jove
  ```

Is this it (maybe you mixed up Joe and Jonathan) or are you looking for another editor?

- If you can't find your favourite editor, maybe `emacs` will feel familiar enough for you. I use emacs24,

  ```
  sudo apt-get install emacs24
  ```
- Otherwise `geany` is a good editor with a GUI

  ```
  sudo apt-get install geany
  ```
- and `nano` is a simple text mode editor (easy to learn, but not as powerful as emacs).